# Session management in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an ASP.NET application. There is a tree link of users on the main page:

1. nagarpalika
2. corporation
3. talukapanchayat

This application runs fine on my PC.

But when I create the virtual directory for my application for functional testing a problem is created.

1. If two users on different computers click the same link (such as 'nagarpalika'), then data belonging to one user is displayed in the other user's pc.
2. The session id changes on one pc to the other one

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are using static classes inside your application?
Static classes inside a web application means that if one user stores values in an instance of that class, all users will see that user's values.

All users use 1 object, so any body can read it or change it.